# Replace gradle dependency with local clone

Tags: java, gradle

I have a java project, managed with gradle, with a remote dependency resolved through a repository.

```
implementation 'org.company:very-big-dependency:2.7.1'
```

I want to clone that dependency, work on the local project, and implement a new feature.

Is there a way to make gradle grab the dependency from local as it did from the repository?

I've tried including the project into my `settings.gradle`

```
include ':app', ":very-big-dependency"
project(':very-big-dependency').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../../very-big-dependency')
```

and defined the dependency on my `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(':very-big-dependency')
```

but when I run `build` gradle complains that it can't find a subproject of the dependency

```
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Project with path ':sub-project' could not be found in project
```

Being that the project built correctly when it was resolved through the repository, this tells me that gradle is not behaving the same way when building the local project.

The dependency's project builds correctly when calling its own build script on the local clone, tests pass and everything is fine.

Is there anything else I need to tell gradle in my project? Do I need to do anything else with the local dependency? Do I need to build a jar every time I want to test this?

**Notes:**

- No IDE is used to handle this
- Project was created via `gradle init`
- I tried importing `:sub-project`, just to get:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':very-big-dependency'.
> Could not get unknown property 'compileJava' for project ':sub-project' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

- I've tried adding a `flatDir` into `repositories` but that led nowhere.

Comment: This question seriously needs a clear and working answer

Answer (score 5):

You could try `includeBuild` + `dependencySubstitution` in `settings.gradle`.

```
// include local clone of the library
includeBuild('../../very-big-dependency') {
    dependencySubstitution {
       // substitute remote dependency with local module
       substitute module('org.company:very-big-dependency') with project(':very-big-dependency')
    }
}
```

See [manual](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#included_build_declaring_substitutions) for more info.

Comment: Do you have path properly set? have you checked the manual for more info?

Comment: had to change it to `with project(':')`.